# Oracle Create a view replacing ids with names in column (not 1nf)

Tags: sql, oracle

We have for example this table:

```
pl_num camp_type  products
1       T         1,2,3
2       B         1,3,4
```

Yeah, I know it's not in 1NF but we need to work with it
because of application loads data in such way.

And we have table DICT_PRODUCT, for example (in reality, there are more than 500 product):

```
id product_name
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

So, what we need is to create view where product_id was replaced by its name in dictionary
---V_TAB1 ---

```
pl_num camp_type  products
1       T         1,b,c
2       B         a,c,d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It will work if products column in `TAB1` contain numbers and not any other characters.

```
WITH prod
     AS (SELECT pl_num, camp_type, TO_NUMBER (TRIM (COLUMN_VALUE)) product
           FROM Tab1 t, XMLTABLE (t.products))
  SELECT prod.pl_num,
         prod.camp_type,
         LISTAGG (d.product_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) products
    FROM prod JOIN dict_product d ON prod.product = d.id
GROUP BY prod.pl_num, prod.camp_type;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ee6f/9)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   select distinct *
    from (
    select t.u_name, u_id, regexp_substr(t.prod,'[^,]+', 1, level) id
    from (select prod,u_id, u_name from  cmdm.t_prod) t
    connect by regexp_substr(prod,'[^,]+',1,level) is not null) ut
    inner join cmdm.t_dct dt
    on ut.id=dt.id
```